# Append query string - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, string

I have a php variable

```
$query="insert into msnowplaying values";
```

Then, I want to append a query string

```
$q1="('1', '$selMovieTitle1', 'ST001', '1', '' )";
$query.=$q1;
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$query');</script>";
```

However, the alert shows nothing. Somehow, there's an error on the console:

```
[10:12:06.851] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @ http://localhost:1234/2013_12_2/controller/doaddNowPlaying.php:1
```

What am I missing? 
I've changed `$q1` to `" a"` and the alert shows `insert into msnowplaying values a`

I don't know what happened, I really need some help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you actually check the output of your script? Use "view source" on your page.

Comment: In your "JavaScript", you are using `'` as string delimiter. The string value in PHP contains `'` characters. Boom!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember, **PHP is parsed on the server**, before the HTML hits the viewer, and **javascript is parsed in the browser**, after the HTML has been received by the user.

What you are sending to the user is written by php into the data as if you wrote it by hand, including anything that may later be interpreted as javascript code.

When you are echoing `$query` to the browser, you are most likely ending up with something that looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('('1', '$selMovieTitle1', 'ST001', '1', '' )');</script>
```

Do you see how this is invalid javascript? You are using unescaped single quotes inside the `alert('..')`. First, if you want to see the correct string in javascript, try this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.addslashes($query).'");</script>';
```

Here we are using the function `addslashes()` ( http://php.net/addslashes ) to escape the quotes appropriately.

Comment: @KevinFlorida Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.addslashes($query).'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\Users\user\Documents\Downloads\Downloads\Compressed\xampp-portable-win32-1.8.3-1-VC11\xampp\htdocs\2013_12_2\controller\doaddNowPlaying.php on line 40

Comment: @teh1 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.addslashes($query).'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\Users\user\Documents\Downloads\Downloads\Compressed\xampp-portable-win32-1.8.3-1-VC11\xampp\htdocs\2013_12_2\controller\doaddNowPlaying.php on line 40

Comment: you didn't use single quotes the way teh1 suggested.  Just look at my answer.. It uses your same logic, but adds slashes before. Try that

Comment: Apologies. I had a typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "insert into msnowplaying values";
$query .= "('1', '$selMovieTitle1', 'ST001', '1', '' )";
$query = addslashes($query);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$query');</script>";
```

Try that

Comment: yes it works, but the main problem is the value of $query is not concatenated with $q1, so the alert just shows insert into msnowplaying values instead of insert into msnowplaying values('1', '$selMovieTitle1', 'ST001', '1', '' )

Comment: I was just showing you your bottom part..  I will edit this for you